# Issue loading images in visual studio 2012

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012

I am new in Visual Studio 2012, I have a project and I need to load some images into a view via javascript, basically I have an array filled with some items description and a path to each image, but when the page loads the page is not able to load the images as it never finds them

The javascript code I am using to achieve this is:

```
      var item = {
        name: "",
        price: 0,
        index: 0,
        picURL: ""
    };

    function Item(name, price, index, picURL) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.index = index;
        this.picURL = picURL;
    }

    function FillArray() {

        var items = new Array();

        items[0] = new Item("Gnome1", 32, 001, "Content/img/gnome7.PNG");
        items[1] = new Item("Gnome2", 15, 002, "Content/img/gnome14.PNG");
        items[2] = new Item("Gnome3", 26, 003, "Content/img/gnome10.PNG");

        return items;
    }


    function addToCart() {
        var items = FillArray();
        var that = this;
        var ul = document.getElementById("list");
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.id = 'li' + items[i].index;
            var currentItem = items[i];

            for (p in currentItem) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                if (p.valueOf() == "picURL") {
                    div.innerHTML = "<img class='miniPic' src='" + currentItem[p].valueOf() + "'/>";
                }
                else if (p.valueOf() == "price") {
                    div.innerHTML = p.valueOf() + " : £" + currentItem[p].valueOf();
                }
                else {
                    div.innerHTML = p.valueOf() + " : " + currentItem[p].valueOf();
                }
                li.appendChild(div);
            }
}
```

But when I call the view this is the answer I get:

GET /Home/Content/img/gnome7.PNG 404 (Not Found)

I've tried to change the location of the files, the path, but nothing seems to work, and it is the same situation when I try to call a json file locally in my project, it also says that I couldn't be found, so I think it could be a sort of configuration of my visual studio but I cannot make it work, can somebody help me please? it is very annoying :(

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you haven't included the images as part of the solution and therefore they aren't getting deployed with your solution.

To fix this, go to the `Solution Explorer` and Navigate to the `Content -> Img` folder. (Make sure the *Show All Files* button at the top of the Solution Explorer is selected).
Inside the img folder  you should see the `gnomeXX` images. If they're grayed-out right click them and choose `Include in Project`.

Try building and running again.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer @Blachshma, yes, the files are included in the solution, and I already did the building and running once again but it still doesn't find the images

Comment: What is the URL you type in the browser? Because I see you're trying to go to `/Home/Content/img/gnome7.PNG` and not `/Content/img/gnome7.PNG 404` - This might be the problem...

Answer (score 0):

spent 5 minutes today on this before I realized the obvious...try ctrl+f5 on the browser......could be a static content/cache issue.

You also want to make sure the build/content settings under "properties" of the relevant files are the same as your other resources that reference correctly.